# ElasticSearch error: 'The client noticed that the server is not a supported distribution of Elasticsearch'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, boto3, amazon-elasticsearch

New to ElasticSearch. I was following this guide to get things set up: https://john.soban.ski/boto3-ec2-to-amazon-elasticsearch.html

I ran the "connect_to_es.py" script there, and oddly it worked the first time, but in a subsequent runs, it started throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../connect_to_es.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(json.dumps(es.info(), indent=4, sort_keys=True))
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 168, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 294, in info
    return self.transport.perform_request(
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 413, in perform_request
    _ProductChecker.raise_error(self._verified_elasticsearch)
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 630, in raise_error
    raise UnsupportedProductError(message)
elasticsearch.exceptions.UnsupportedProductError: The client noticed that the server is not a supported distribution of Elasticsearch
```

The elasticsearch python library version I have is 7.14, and my elasticsearch on AWS is running 7.10. Any thoughts on what's going on here?

Copy of code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
import boto3
import json

host = '<url>.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-east-1'

service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth = awsauth,
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = True,
    connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
)

print(json.dumps(es.info(), indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out!  I updated the blog post you reference: https://john.soban.ski/boto3-ec2-to-amazon-elasticsearch.html

Answer (score 7):

Seems like downgrading fixed it `pip3 install 'elasticsearch<7.14.0'`

Comment: unfortunately the aws service is not actually Elasticsearch. that check is there to ensure that the Elasticsearch client is talking to proper Elasticsearch, and that the functionality the client expects is available

Comment: downgrading to 1 version lesser than `7.14` did not work for me. But to version: `7.13`, it worked.

Answer (score 5):

New `elasticsearch-js` has an issue:

- [The new product version check rejects oss distributions?](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/1519)

Downgrading it to lower version (e.g. 7.13) should help.

Comment: Original post was about python, but if you're concerned with javascript, you might want to look at OpenSearch-JS (opensearch-project/opensearch-js on github).

Comment: elasticsearch-js does not seem to be related to Python

Answer (score 1):

As some of the other answers indicate, you can downgrade right now but [opensearch-py](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-py) is a better long term solution

It should be a drop-in replacement for elasticsearch-py and it will be updated and patched over time. It supports OSS Elasticsearch and OpenSearch.

Comment: I don't know why anyone has marked this down, it's a valid answer, and is indeed the long term future for any of us running Opensearch in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs because of the version conflict. Version of elasticsearch python library and elasticsearch should be the same.

In my case, elasticsearch version was 7.10 on AWS and I was using elasticsearch python library version 7.15 with my Django project. I removed it and installed new python library with version 7.10 in Django project and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error by making following changes in `Gemfile` -

I changed -

```
gem 'elasticsearch'
```

to -

```
gem 'elasticsearch', '~> 7.1'
```

Ideally, I downgraded from 7.18(current version as of today) to 7.1